# Flutter websocket channel can't catch some messages

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, stream-builder

We have an old websocket api that i am using right now. Normally the websocket works just fine but for some commands it sends me 3 different messages nearly at the same time but the flutter code cannot catch them always. Sometimes it just gets the las messages, sometimes 2 of them and ver rarely 3 of them.

I did some research and find out that due to the working principle of StreamBuilder, it may just not get some messages and lost it forever.

Do you have any idea about how can i solve this problem?
I can just add some delay to the message sending parts in the websocket code but i do not think this is the most healty way and some other part may be broken since the websocket code is old.